# mongodb: how can i get a array result

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have written a MongoDB query that looks like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      categories: {
        $addToSet: "$category"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      categories: 1
    }
  }
])
```

but the result is:

```
[
  {
    "categories": [
      "Enhancement",
      "Bug"
    ]
  }
]
```

how can I get a result like this:

```
["Enhancement", "Bug"]
```

[mongodb playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vmirKc-i72R)

Comment: you can't, query `aggregation` return  [corsor](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/glossary/#std-term-cursor) for the documents produced by the final stage of the aggregation pipeline. and it needs `explain()` and/or `toArray` to  iterate through a cursor to retrieve results, please refer to https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/

Comment: so you need to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB is a document database, it will always return a document or an array of documents.  There is no query method in MongoDB that will return a scalar value or an array of scalar values.

You can do modification on the client side.  If you are using javascript, you could get that result with:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      categories: {
        $addToSet: "$category"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      categories: 1
    }
  }
])[0].categories
```

Answer (score -1):

You can maybe try to modify the query to include an additional aggregation stage using `$unwind` and `$replaceRoot` operators. Tell me if it works for you.

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
      {
        $group: {
          _id: null,
          categories: {
            $addToSet: "$category"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        $unwind: "$categories"
      },
      {
        $replaceRoot: {
          newRoot: "$categories"
        }
      }
    ])
```